# Definition with numbered equation

Tags: equations

I am trying to make a definition with two numbered equations. But the space between definition and equations is big.
I guess I have not to separate definition and equation environment.

```
\begin{definition*}
\textbf{(A-diag)} : Some text for the definition
\end{definition*}
\begin{equation}
       (\forall \varepsilon > 0) (\exists N \in \mathbb{N})(\forall s \in \psi (\Sigma_{f_{i}}) \wedge n \geq N)     
    \label{def:a-diag}
\end{equation}
where the diagnosability condition function D is as in logical diagnosability.
\begin{equation}
    D(st) = 1
\label{def:a-diag-D}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: You guess right: if they're part of the definition, put `\end{definition}` *after* the last equation.

Comment: If the equations form part of the definition, include them as part of the definition. It's really that straight-forward.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not sure now that my answer is what you need. Is the text "where the diagnosability condition function D is as in logical diagnosability." supposed to be a little intervening text between both equations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both equations should be included in the `definition` body.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
\textbf{(A-diag)}: Some text for the definition
\begin{equation}
       (\forall \varepsilon > 0) (\exists N \in \mathbb{N})(\forall s \in \psi (\Sigma_{f_{i}}) \wedge n \geq N),     
    \label{def:a-diag}
\end{equation}    
where the diagnosability condition function $D$ is as in logical diagnosability.
\begin{equation}
    D(st) = 1.
\label{def:a-diag-D}
\end{equation}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: I'd avoid the second example: the spacing is just wrong.

Comment: @egreg Yes, you're right. I've suppressed it. Thanks.